# Selective VPN split tunnelling to external hosts

Tags: vpn, split-tunnel

I'm looking for help on how to set up a VPN with split tunneling where staff can do the following;

- Work remotely.
- Access internal networks through the VPN
- Access MOST external hosts directly (i.e. not through the VPN)
- Access some specific external hosts through the VPN

I've got the first 3 working using split tunneling, but can't figure out how to do the 4th.

The 4th is so that we access some customer sites that have white-listed IPs coming from our company such that we can login with special accounts that have additional privileges.

For example, right now when we access www.acme.com;

- Directly from home (i.e. with no VPN) we cannot login as our home IP's are not on acme's white-list.
- Via full VPN (i.e. without split-tunneling) we can login because we came through our companies network, which is in acme's white-list.
- Via split-tunneled VPN we cannot login because we're back to having our home IP's.

Ideally I like to be able to specify that traffic to the host name "acme.com" is routed through the VPN, rather than having to specify the customer's IP addresses as these can change. However, if addresses are the only way to make it work, that would be OK.

Any help would be most appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: What VPN software are you using, and did you need to do anything special to implement #2 (accessing internal networks)?

Comment: The VPN is OpenVPN based. Server; AWS client VPC endpoint (split-tunnel enabled, DNS servers 172.31.0.2, 8.8.8.8 (the 1st being internal AWS Route53), route table entries pushed to clients; 172.31.0.0/16 0.0.0.0/0 . Clients; use Viscosity & OpenVPN apps. OVPN config on clients; #viscosity dns full \n client \n dev tun \n proto udp \n remote random.cvpn-endpoint-xxxxxxxxx.prod.clientvpn.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 1194 \n remote-random-hostname \n resolv-retry infinite \n nobind \n persist-key \n persist-tun \n remote-cert-tls server \n cipher AES-256-GCM \n verb 3 \n <ca>...</ca> \n reneg-sec 0